# Socket.io store socket to send emits later

Tags: node.js, angular, sockets, io

So im currently developing a socket server to listen to many users and later sending data to the others. 
The problem with this is I need to store the socket object to emit data later.
But my client doesnt receive any notifications.

Just if I do it directly after the connection.

```
io.on('connection', (socket): void => {
    socket.emit('hello', { text: "hello" }); // WORKS FINE

socket.on('init', (socket): void => {
    socket.emit('hello', { text: "hello" }); // DOESNT WORK ANYMORE
}

}
```

So the problem is I cant store it because it even work in the init. 
If I log the socket it displays the object without a problem...

**Im using**:
    - Frontend: Angular 5 Socket IO
    - Backend: NodeJS Express Socket IO

Hopefully there is someone who knows what Im doing wrong. Thank you for reading